# ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous.

Tags: python, pandas

I've seen a few posts with this error but they don't apply to this particular situation.

Say my dataframe is as follows...

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,20,size=(10, 2)), columns=list('AB'))


    A   B
0  12  12
1  15   3
2   3  12
3   4  11
4  12   9
5   0   4
6  19  12
7   5  19
8  11  16
9  13   8
```

I want to create a column `factor` which depends on the value of column `A`.
Let's say if `df[A]<=10` then `factor=5` else `factor=8`

I tried:

```
df['factor'] = 5 if df['A'] <= 10 else 8
```

But I get an error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Comment: It seems to me that `df['A']` is a list, not a single value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need this:

```
df['factor'] = np.where( df.A <= 10, 5, 8)
```

---

You can also use a mask

```
mask = df['A'] <= 10 
df['factor'] = 8 
df.loc[mask, 'factor'] = 5
```

---

**Note:** the answer in [Truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921951/truth-value-of-a-series-is-ambiguous-use-a-empty-a-bool-a-item-a-any-o) explains neatly the reason behind the error.